# Maximum Likelihood estimator for family of binomial distributions

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

For the below example, I am considering Heads as a success and Tails as a failure, when I toss a coin.

(Ex: The first row in the the below tables says, when I tossed the coin 10 times I got 3 Successes and the probability of success is 0.3).

Binomial Distribution Example
[image]

Now, considering the fact that the Probability of successes might change by increase in trials, I know the maximum likelihood estimator of binomial distribution is Number of Successes/ Total Number of Trials. I feel calculating the MLE for this kind of data is not that straightforward, COuld someone tell me if I am missing something?

P.S: This is a research based question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you tossing the same coin always?

Comment: Thanks for responding Alecos Papadopoulos. Yes I am tossing the same coin.

Comment: I gather you're doing something else than actually tossing a coin. Since you mention the possibility of $p$ changing, you should probably mention the actual application, or more strongly emphasize the changing $p$, because with actual coins the probability doesn't tend to change.

Comment: Thanks Glen. This is more of research related question, I had to change the example. Could you please give me your email I'd so that I can send the questions I am looking answers for?

Comment: Jason I understand why you ask, so I am sorry, but no - I participate on a site like this specifically in order that I don't give individual advice - I want my answers to help more than one person at a time. The benefit of answering a question here is that instead of reaching one person with an answer, (adding up to maybe a few hundreds of people across a couple of decades of effort), I can potentially reach many thousands in the space of a few years. So if I'm doing it for free, I'm definitely doing it in public, in a place that makes my answers easy to find -- and that's how SE works.

Answer (score 3):

Since per clarification comment, we are tossing the same coin, then in each single Bernoulli trial the probability is the same, $p$, it is not affected by number of trials (assuming also an unbiased way of tossing). If moreover we can assume that all Bernoulli trials are independent, and that each sub-sample consists of different tosses (i.e. the $n=20$ sample does not contain the $10$ tosses of the $n=10$ sample), then, viewed together, we have an independent but non-identically distributed sample of realizations from $10$ Binomials that have the same unknown probability parameter, but different "number of trials" parameters (although known and deterministic), $S_i(n_i,p), i=1,2,3,...,10$, corresponding to  $n$-parameters $10,20,30,...,100$.

Then the joint likelihood of this sample is (ignoring constants that do not include the unknown parameter)

$$L \propto \prod_{i=1}^{10}p^{k_i}(1-p)^{n_i-k_i} = p^{\sum k_i}(1-p)^{\sum (n_i-k_i)}$$

where $k_i$'s are the obtained number of successes

So the log-likelihood is

$$\ln L = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}k_i\right)\ln p + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}(n_i-k_i)\right)\ln (1-p)$$

You should get

$$\hat p = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{10}k_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{10}n_i}$$

as should be expected, since you pooled i.i.d. Bernoulli draws, and so the estimator treated them as $\sum_{i=1}^{10}n_i$ draws from a Bernoulli $(p)$ RV in which we had $\sum_{i=1}^{10}k_i$ successes.

Comment: Thanks again  Alecos Papadopoulos. It is very clear they way you explained it. But, I just have one question. When you said "(i.e. the n=20 sample does not contain the 10 tosses of the n=10 sample)". Do you think the MLE would change when the 20 tosses contains the previous 10 tosses too?

Comment: @JasonMathews In such a case the $10$ corresponding Binomial RVs are no longer independent, and so their joint probability mass function (which will lead to the log-likelihood) is not the product of the individual pmfs. With a different log-likelihood, you should get a different estimate.